# SQL how to get the top two values only

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query which works, however I want to store only the first two rows into variables.  This is in a loop so that's where j comes from but this is the only relevant part

```
SELECT MNO, COUNT(MNO) AS NUM_ALBUMS
FROM PERFORM
WHERE PERFORM.SNO IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT S.ANO
    FROM SONG S
    WHERE S.SNO IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT P.SNO
        FROM PERFORM P
        WHERE j IN P.MNO
        GROUP BY P.SNO
    )
)
AND PERFORM.MNO != 1
GROUP BY MNO
ORDER BY COUNT(MNO) DESC;
```

This returns something similar to this

```
       MNO NUM_ALBUMS
---------- ----------
     2      3
     3      3
     4      2
```

I would like to store the top two MNOs along with the top two counts into variables to return in a print statement.  Can anyone help please?  I can edit with more info if necessary.

Comment: So, are MNO's 2 and 3 the top two, or are 2 and 3 the top count and 4 the second?  What if you have more that two with the same top count?

Comment: 2 and 3 are the top two, it does not matter if counts are the same I just want to store the top two rows from that query into variables.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: You don't have to group or distinct in `IN ()`. Condition `WHERE PERFORM.SNO IN (
    SELECT S.ANO
    FROM SONG S
    WHERE S.SNO IN (
        SELECT P.SNO
        FROM PERFORM P
        WHERE j IN P.MNO
    )
)` is sufficient and might be faster.

Comment: Josh, what if 2,3, and 4 all have the same value?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the results returned by your SQL Query using the FETCH ... ONLY clause

The limit clause takes in 2 values: the **offset** and then **number of rows** required.

Ex: If you wanted rows 10-20, your limit clause would be

```
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

To return the first 2 rows only, your query would have to be then

```
SELECT MNO, COUNT(MNO) AS NUM_ALBUMS
FROM PERFORM
WHERE PERFORM.SNO IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT S.ANO
    FROM SONG S
    WHERE S.SNO IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT P.SNO
        FROM PERFORM P
        WHERE j IN P.MNO
        GROUP BY P.SNO
    )
)
AND PERFORM.MNO != 1
GROUP BY MNO
ORDER BY COUNT(MNO) DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Read up here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1

Comment: `LIMIT 0,2` is invalid in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for that! Fixed answer to match Oracle dialect. I was thinking about MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
SELECT mno, num_albums
  FROM (SELECT MNO, COUNT(MNO) AS NUM_ALBUMS
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(MNO) DESC) rn
          FROM PERFORM
         WHERE PERFORM.SNO IN (
               SELECT DISTINCT S.ANO
                 FROM SONG S
                WHERE S.SNO IN (
                      SELECT DISTINCT P.SNO
                        FROM PERFORM P
                       WHERE j IN P.MNO
                GROUP BY P.SNO)
           AND PERFORM.MNO != 1
         GROUP BY MNO)
 WHERE rn < 3;
```